# Write data from 1st occurrence of string to last occurrence of a string in a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want write data whatever coming between 1st occurrence of a string and last occurrence in a file to another file using shell script.

I tried using the following sed command which is printing the lines in which string match is there.

```
sed -n '/Air/p' ashu.txt
```

Example : ashu.txt contains

```
I am a good student
Air is polluted 
water is not free 
now Expensive Air will be
```

The above sed command is giving output as below

```
Air is polluted 
now Expensive Air will be
```

But i want the out as below.

```
Air is polluted 
water is not free 
now Expensive Air
```

Please bear with my text  alignment in post.

Comment: What if there is just one occurrence of `Air`?

Comment: Then it should print that line contain the word "Air"

Answer (score 1):

When I hear about the **last** *something* in a file, I usually think "reverse the file and ... the **first** *something* in the file"

So:

```
sed -n '/Air/,$p' file | tac | sed -n '/Air/,$p' | tac
```

which is:

1. print from the first Air to the end of the file
2. reverse that stream
3. print from the first Air to the end of the stream
4. reverse that stream to restore the original order.

More DRY:

```
f() { sed -n '/Air/,$p' | tac; }
f <file | f
```

Comment: I wasn't brave enough to post that but you are right